# How to reduce the size of .bin file

Tags: microcontroller, atmel

I wanted to reduce the size of my .bin file to load my application program directly in the sram location of the controller(AT93SAM9X35) without using an bootloader. Right now .bin is 89kb i want it below 24kb is it possible???

Comment: You will first have to identify what's in your `.bin` file. Then you can decide what's not necessary. Finally you can remove that stuff. What do you think how the reader of your question can give you more response without the first step done?

Comment: I already remove unused stuff...now in my code lib files and application code is their.

Comment: Actually what is happening is that my ddram is crashed and i wanted to load my .bin file in sram location so is their any way to load my application code without second level bootloader..

Comment: not nearly providing enough information.  it is very likely that your application is too big to fit, not to mention unlikely to run unless you re-link it, then  you have the problem of .data and .bss that you need to find  ram for.

Comment: The short answer of course is if you want your binary smaller you have to remove some stuff.